# Is there an alternative to CHESS for testing programs written with Task Parallel Library

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-4.0, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am looking for a tool that will allow me to execute unit tests over all possible interleavings (spelling?) with a program that was written with Task Parallel Library constructs.  Alternatively, how could I run CHESS with dotNET 4.0?

Comment: Since interleavings are generated by parallel threads, you can easily get an exponential set of possible interleavings, and that's impractical to enumerate at runtime.   The usual solution is to use static analysis tools to determine which interleavings matter and to (cleverly!) ensure that none of them get you into trouble.  So you need some kind of offlne analysis tool.

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Peli/Data-Race-Detection-with-CHESS

Comment: It appears the guys at Microsoft decided to make it easier on Googlers and called it Cuzz.  "Coming to a dev box near you."  http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/cuzz/

Comment: The question remains, how do I test my programs today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a commercially available tool, Jinx. Which looks similar to CHESS and supports .NET 4 (according to the docs).

http://www.corensic.com/
http://wiki.corensic.com/wiki/Main_Page

Last I looked CHESS only worked with VS 2008. Not sure what the status of the project is.

I've not used Jinx but it looks like it would be worth investigating. YMMV.